# Is it possible to create a Binding Library from a sample code even if it doesn't work / it's full of errors?

Tags: kotlin, xamarin, binding

I was thinking that I need to be able to build and run a sample code first to make sure all of its functionalities work. Before I could create a Bindings Library out of it, and use it in my Xamarin app.

This is the sample code:
https://github.com/hannesa2/LiveEdgeDetection
This code uses OpenCV and I need it for my Xamarin app

I try to build and run it, but there are endless of errors. I do not have a lot of experience using Kotlin either. So I was wondering if it is possible to skip this part. I am a beginner, but from how I understand Bindings Library it should be possible? Ideally, the git repository should successfully work elsewhere. Maybe not just in my computer/Android Studio.

Although, I would understand if it's not possible either.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't create a binding library for a native library that can't be built.  But you should be able to download a pre-built version of the library and use that for your binding library.

Comment: How can I download a pre-built version of the library?

Comment: the github repo has a jitpack link, presumably you can get it there

Comment: Okay, thank you so much